# Inaccessible link when accessed from anorther page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, hyperlink

i have encountered an issue with a micropayment service i'm using.
the thing is i embedded the payment page on my website as an iframe.
but in the last two days i've been getting complaints about the payment method not showing up.

the issue is when i access the payment link from the company website (not mine), it works perfectly.
but when i copy the same link and paste it in another tab all i get is a blank page.

example :

```
<iframe src="http://www.iropay.com/?p=5144" style="width:499px;height:402px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

that is the real company link, when you access it, it won't work

P.S : the company that provides the payment method already sets up the link to be public, but i only can access it when i open it from the company website.

i hope it's not a long useless description of the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There may be differences in the way the company page utilises the iframe to the way your site does. However, we would need to know how your code is attempting to call the payment process in order to find the problem. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Comment: No code, not even the name of the payment-service...

Comment: going to `http://www.iropay.com/?p=5144` does nothing your `src` is bad.

Comment: it was working perfectly buddy, but then the owners of the website did something with the links, the page still works, but only when accessed from the their website.
check the image behow :
http://www.openscreenshot.com/HJspadN9g

Answer (score 0):

You try disabled  chromium-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
or you can the answers [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)